# How to create and append to a log text file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, logging, activexobject

Im new to Javascript and HTML and I'm trying to append to a log file to keep track of what is going on in my code etc.

I have a Logging.js file:

```
function WriteLog(message)
{
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fh = fso.OpenTextFile("Path\file.txt", 8, true);
    fh.WriteLine(message);
    fh.Close()
}
```

And then in my HTML I specify the source:

```
<script src="filepath\Logging.js" type="text/JavaScript"> </script>
```

and then call the function on load:

```
<body onload="WriteLog('hello')">
```

However, nothing gets written to the file! 
Am I doing this right? Thanks!

Update: Corrected some typo's in my question

Comment: `src` isn't spelt `scr` (and ActiveX has very limited browser support with significant security restrictions on it).

Answer (score 0):

If you've got exactly this:

```
 <script scr="filepath\Logging.js" type="text/JavaScript" </script>
```

Your js file isn't included. Change to this:

```
 <script src="filepath/Logging.js" type="text/JavaScript"></script>
 <!--    ^^^          ^                                  ^      -->
```

Note the 3 differences.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `console.log("...")`? This logs to the console and every decent browser has something built in to show it. E.g. F12 for Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Found out my problem. In my filepath I was using single '\' instead of double '\'. Apparently single '\' can generate escape sequences?

For example:

```
C:\\Users\\Tom\\Logging.js
```

Instead of:

```
C:\Users\Tom\Logging.js
```